# Can you send emails from cases from within the Salesforce1 app?

Tags: email, salesforce1-app

Is there an equivalent to the standard "Send Email" function on cases in the Salesforce1 mobile app? I want to reply to emails that are on a case and send new emails from within the app, but I can't find out how to do that. Maybe I don't see through the app's UI.

I don't want to use my phones email apps, because the emails won't be added to the case and they won't include the reference numbers that are used by email2case.

(I'm using the Android version of Salesforce1.)

Comment: Have you tried setting up a record Publisher Action for sending emails from Cases?  http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/actions_impl_guide.pdf

Comment: That would be a solution. But as SF announced that the send email function will be coming in the next release (see https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l2Q4AAI), I'm just waiting for that.